# Go to XY tool not working when clicked in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I am using ArcGIS 10.3. When I click on 'Go to XY tool', located on toolbar, it doesn't open.

What is the possible solution to fix this problem, so I could open 'Go to XY tool' in ArcGIS 10.3?

Comment: If the linked question is not the same as your problem, please [edit] your question and include more information about *what* that is not working.

Comment: @PolyGeo I have read this link but it doesn't contains any possible solutions

Comment: Then please explain further what it is that you can't get working. Use the [Edit] button beneath your question to update it.

Comment: I did not vote to close as a duplicate I voted to close because your question in its current state is unclear.

Comment: @PolyGeo I have revisited my text, hope this makes clear.

Comment: Have you tried choosing another tool and then returning to this one?  Have you tried deleting your Normal.mxt?

Comment: Have you tried using the 'Customization' option to remove the short-cut and then re add it?

Comment: No, I didn't removed it earlier, the program was successfully installed although. Still, this tool doesn't responds.